# Transform Numbers to Text

Tags: sql, ssas, cube, sql-server-data-tools, olap-cube

A field in my cube contains numerical values which I would like transformed and displayed as text.

For example

1 is a sale
2 is a return

etc

Is a named caculation best?

Comment: Can you supply some more information? Maybe some code? 
Show us your problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Easiest way to do this would be with a case statement,

```
SELECT 
   CASE someValue
      WHEN 1 THEN 'sale' 
      WHEN 2 THEN 'return' 
   END
FROM MyTable ;
```